# CSS3: transform flickers on FF

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I try to animate a pseudo element width css3. Everything is ok. But on Firefox (43.0.3) at the end of the animation the font flickers:

```css
div {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  color:red;
  font-size:100px;
  background:black;
  transform:matrix(1.0001,0.00,0.00,1.0001,0,0);
}
div:before {
  content:"test";
  font-size:100px;
  color:white;
  margin:0 0 0 200px;
  display:block;
  animation:test 2s ease-in-out 1s both;
  transform:matrix(1.0001,0.00,0.00,1.0001,0,0);
}
@keyframes test {
  0% {
    transform:matrix(1.0001,0.00,0.00,1.0001,0,0);
  }
  50% {
    transform:matrix(1.50,0.00,0.00,1.50,0,0);
  }
  100% {
    transform:matrix(1.0001,0.00,0.00,1.0001,0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Edit] I didnt get the point how to link to jsfiddle. so heres the link:
jsfiddle.net SLASH focgzeye

Anyone could help?

Comment: Seems OK in Firefox 43 on OS X (Retina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add line-height same as font-size:

```
line-height:100px;
```

Tested on Firefox 43.0.1 but with the same flicker problem.

[Here the jsfiddle update.](http://jsfiddle.net/focgzeye/1/)